# Why don't my SQL results match my Linq results?

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql

When I run this Query in SQL I get what I want:

```
SELECT Auckland_Park.Formative.[Formative Name]
FROM Auckland_Park.LearningUnit 
INNER JOIN Auckland_Park.Formative 
ON Auckland_Park.LearningUnit.ID = Auckland_Park.Formative.FK_LU 
INNER JOIN Auckland_Park.Reference 
INNER JOIN Auckland_Park.Course 
ON Auckland_Park.Reference.FK_Course = Auckland_Park.Course.ID 
ON Auckland_Park.LearningUnit.ID = Auckland_Park.Reference.FK_LU
WHERE Auckland_Park.Course.Name = 'BI'
```

My result:

```
Querying SQL Build 
Report Develop 
Java App Develop 
Andriod App Set up
SharePoint Server
```

But when I work with my C# app I'm using LINQ to SQL, my LINQ Query looks like this:

```
//LINQ Query to fill Foramtive Name ComboBox
CTUDataContext data = new CTUDataContext();
var course = (from r in data.LearningUnits                      
              join a in data.Formatives
              on r.ID equals a.FK_LU
              join f in data.References
              on r.ID equals f.FK_LU
              join g in data.Courses 
              on f.FK_LU equals g.ID
              where g.Name == ("BI")
              select new
              {
                  formativeName = a.Formative_Name,
                  ID = a.ID

              } 
              ).ToList();
txtFormativeName.ItemsSource = course;
txtFormativeName.DisplayMemberPath = "formativeName";
txtFormativeName.SelectedValuePath = "ID";
```

It seems the same, but I'm not getting the same result that I'm getting with the SQL Query above.

Comment: whats the result of Linq query?

Comment: The result comes from the same table but not under my WHERE clause that is "BI"..

Comment: Have you looked at the SQL generated by your LINQ query?

Comment: What do you mean by "but not under my where clause"? You need to be a *lot* clearer about what you expect vs what you're actually seeing.

Comment: the WHERE gives me the result of the SQl query above.. But in LINQ I'm not getting that result.. the result I'm getting comes from the same table but not the rows I want.

Comment: Your SQL query even runs? Two inner joins back to back without using "on ..." after each inner join

Comment: Xander, you need to post: The SQL generated by LINQ to SQL (use SQL Profiler) and the results you are getting with LINQ (maybe as a screenshot). Voting to close now but I'll retract the vote as soon as the question becomes answerable.

Comment: Do you get the good results if you remove the 'where' and the 'select new'.  Don't jump to any conclusions until you properly diagnosis the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
>     //LINQ Query to fill Foramtive Name ComboBox
> CTUDataContext data = new CTUDataContext();
> var course = (from r in data.LearningUnits                      
>               join a in data.Formatives
>               on r.ID equals a.FK_LU
>               join f in data.References
>               on r.ID equals f.FK_LU
>               join g in data.Courses 
>               on f.FK_LU equals g.ID
>               where g.Name == ("BI")
>               select new
>               {
>                   formativeName = a.Formative_Name,
>                   ID = a.ID
>
>               } 
>               ).ToList();
> txtFormativeName.ItemsSource = course;
> txtFormativeName.DisplayMemberPath = "formativeName";
> txtFormativeName.SelectedValuePath = "ID";
> ```

ANSWER:

```
on f.FK_LU equals g.ID


f.FK_LU
```

must be replaced with

```
f.FK_Course
```